# Using/Acessing jQuery UI from index.html to frame in index.html

Tags: jquery, html

I have been ordered to use frames (not iframes) to setup a project.  I've created teh frames and set the context overwrite for frames across all frames.  The issue I am having is I am not able to use jQuery UI across these frames.  Does anyone know of a way to access the jQuery UI across frames?

```
**main.html**
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<frameset rows="*,660,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
    <frame src="border.html" name="border" title="border" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" tabindex="-1" />
    <frame src="test.html" name="body" title="body" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" tabindex="1" />
    <frame src="border.html" name="border" title="border" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" tabindex="-1" />
</frameset>
<noframes></noframes>
</html>

**test.html**
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = function(a){return top.$(a, this.document);} /* jQuery Context Overwrite */

    $("#slider").slider();
</script>

<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was able to use jQuery across frames with the context overwrite but I cannot access the UI.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: try including jquery-ui in test.html as well

Comment: Did that and it says jQuery is undefined.  I really hope not to include the jQuery-ui on every page just the index.html

Comment: I mean main.html not index.html sorry

Comment: You know the `<frameset>` tag was deprecated in HTML5? Traditional frames are not supported in HTML5. With that in mind, it may be better to rework your layout than trying to work with deprecated items.